# Booleans + while loops =?

Tags: c#, boolean, while-loop

I've got an odd issue with the below code (I've stripped out the parts that are irrelevant, and any classes/functions referenced are working as expected):

```
int curNumRooms = 0;

while(curNumRooms < numberOfRooms) {
    int w = Random.Range(minimumRoomSize, maximumRoomSize+1);
    int h = Random.Range(minimumRoomSize, maximumRoomSize+1);

    int x = Random.Range(0, (int)levelSize.x - w - 1);
    int y = Random.Range(0, (int)levelSize.y - h - 1);          

    Rectangle newRoom = new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);

    bool failed = false;

    foreach (Rectangle otherRoom in rooms) {
        if(otherRoom != null) {                 
            if (newRoom.Intersect(otherRoom)) {
                failed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!failed) {          
        rooms[curNumRooms] = newRoom;
        curNumRooms++;
    }

}
```

For some reason, failed always evaluates to true. I threw in a couple debug messages, and oddly enough, failed evaluates twice -- the first time, in the foreach loop, it evaluates correctly. The second time, it evaluates to false. If I initialize failed as true, then it evaluates to true the second time, almost as if the while loop was being run twice, and ignoring the foreach loop the second time around.

Why is this?

---

EDIT 1: Here's my Rectangle class and the variables concerned:

```
public class Rectangle {
        public int x1;
        public int y1;
        public int x2;
        public int y2;

        public bool Intersect(Rectangle other) {
            return (x1 <= other.x2 && x2 >= other.x1 && y1 <= other.y2 && y2 <= other.y1);      
        }

        public Rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
            this.x1 = x;
            this.x2 = x+w;
            this.y1 = y;
            this.y2 = y + h;
        }

        public Rectangle() {

        }

        public Vector2 Center() {
            int centerX = (x1 + x2) / 2;
            int centerY = (y1 + y2) / 2;

            Vector2 center = new Vector2(centerX, centerY);

            return center;
        }
    }
```

Here's the variables I used:

```
public Vector2 levelSize = new Vector2(80,30);
public int maximumRoomSize = 10;
public int minimumRoomSize = 5;
```

Comment: What are the other `Rect`s in `rooms`?

Comment: What does your Intersect function look like? What are the values of minRoomSize,maxRoomSize and levelSize before you enter this code segment?  Without that information,its difficult to tell why your Intersect function always returns true.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer, just more Rects, created in the same while loop and added to the `rooms` array. `rooms[curNumRooms] = newRoom;` is the line that adds the current Rect to the `rooms` array. @Yasser, if you need the Intersect function and those variables, I'll edit them in. However, it does seem as if it's an error with the code segment I posted - the Intersect function evaluates correctly, but then somehow `failed` is set back to false regardless of any of the other values.

Comment: Yes, if you can edit those in, it would be eaiser to see whats happening.

Comment: Okay, will do. Give me a minute.

Comment: What's this line for: `if(otherRoom != null) {` - there shouldn't be any null rooms in the collection, right?

Comment: That's because I'm initializing my array rooms to be the amount of rooms I'll have in the future; all of the rooms are initialized null, then I loop through and set them.

Comment: I'm trying to run your code - what is `Random.Range`?  Can I just use `System.Random.Next` instead?

Comment: Random.Range is *another* custom function. As you may have guessed, I'm using an API library which isn't very well known. @FreeAsInBeer Cool, I'll have a look. :)

Comment: FreeAsInBeer, you have done it. Thanks for fixing my math, I never guessed that that was the root of the error, as I copied it from a tutorial. (Yes, I'm just getting into C#)

Comment: @Elliot - I ended up running it and still didn't have a problem, I got a collision (even with the bad Intersect routine) - I added my observations to my original answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're math is wrong. This:

```
public bool Intersect(Rectangle other) {
    return (x1 <= other.x2 && x2 >= other.x1 && y1 <= other.y2 && y2 <= other.y1);
}
```

Should be changed to (Note I change the `<=` to `>=` in the latter part of the statement):

```
public bool Intersect(Rectangle other) {
    return (x1 <= other.x2 && x2 >= other.x1 && y1 <= other.y2 && y2 >= other.y1);
}
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help out. I run into these issues from time to time on code that seems to be a no-brainer, but can give you trouble if you don't pay attention.

Comment: If I had a penny for every no-brainer that's given me an issue I'd be a millionaire. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not positive, but your use of Rectangle.Intersect might not be right.  Intersect returns a rectangle that represents the intersection of the two specified rectangles, or an "empty" rectangle if there is no intersection.  You might try [IntersectsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith.aspx) instead - this returns a boolean.

Comment: But how is the returned rectangle evaluating to a boolean ?

Comment: I'm actually using a custom Rectangle class -- I avoided using Rect as my class name as I thought that was a standard class. Perhaps I should have named it Rect instead, and avoided using Rectangle.

Comment: @Bala: Most likely it's just evaluating to `true` if it's not `null`. Otherwise it would evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your loop logic that would be setting `failed` incorrectly.  If you're confident that the method shouldn't fail on the second loop, check your helper methods, in particular `Rectangle.Intersect`.  Adding more trace output will also be useful for your debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of the while loop failed is REinitialized to false

Comment: that appears to be the expected behavior; the `rooms` array is being populated in the while loop with a number of rooms that all don't intersect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by evaluates twice? Surely after the break it exits the for loop. Perhaps try clean your solution, delete the hidden obj directory and then rebuild?

Comment: That's what I thought, but apparently not. I have no other explanation for why `failed` is always set to false.

Comment: @Elliot Bonneville - I thought you said failed always evaluates to true?

Comment: No, if I initialize(ed) it to true, it would always evaluate to true; if I initialize(ed) it to false, it would always evaluate to false; in other words, Intercept wasn't evaluating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding the Intersect method I'd say it has to be that that is causing your problem.  You say the first iteration of the while loop (guess on my part - your question is vague in parts) gives the correct evaluation of failed (I'm guessing this is at the line `if (!failed)`).  The Intersect method is not called here because there are no rooms in the rooms array, thus you get failed being false from the initialization of failed variable.  Then on the second time through the while loop there is a room in the rooms array, the Intersect method evaluates incorrectly for your purposes and always says there is an intersection.  I can see now that @FreeAsInBeer has seen an error in the Intersect method.